# Angular 5.2 can't build application with aot and i18n, get error: Cannot read property 'range' of null

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

The error occured when I build my application with Internationalization (i18n) and with AOT compiler. With JIT compiller my application builds well.

Please don't suggest me to use `ng build --aot=false`. It's dirty solution, I need a performance and less size of bundles.

To reproduce the error: create new project, add content to app.component.html:

```
<h1 i18n="site header|An introduction header for this sample">Hello i18n!</h1>
```

Create the translation with command:

```
ng xi18n --outputPath src/locale --outFile messages.ru.xlf
```

Add translation text in the tag <target></target>.
And build application with command:

```
ng build --aot --prod --i18n-file=src/locale/messages.ru.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=ru
```

The error text will be such about:

> ERROR in chunk main [initial] [name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js Cannot
>   read property 'range' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'range'
>   of null
>       at enterNode (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:146:14)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:125:24)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:134:24)
>       at enterNode (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:149:18)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:138:25)
>       at enterNode (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:149:18)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:125:24)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:134:24)
>       at enterNode (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:149:18)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:125:24)
>       at getPathInAst (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:134:24)
>       at info.moduleScope.variables.forEach.variable (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:536:23)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at modulesWithInfo.forEach.info (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:524:34)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at ConcatenatedModule.source (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\angular-test\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:516:19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

`ng build --prod -vc=true`

or just -vc because true is default value for --prod

vc is alias of vendor chunk and means use a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.
For some reason it doesn't works fine by default in this version of angular cli

Answer (score 1):

I found how to shut up this error, but I don't know what cause this error. Please suggest me source of the error if know the webpack. Shortly speaking my solution is follow:

in the file `my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:146` add code:

```
    if (n === null)
        return undefined;
```

The total code must be about this:

```
function enterNode(n) {
    if (n === null)
        return undefined;

    const r = n.range;
    if(r) {
        if(r[0] <= nr[0] && r[1] >= nr[1]) {
            const path = getPathInAst(n, node);
            if(path) {
                path.push(n);
                return path;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```